# Query containing array

Tags: php, array, mysql

I want to get the query result that contains all entries from array and some data from the DB.
It's like the array is a DB table and by `left join` I connect the data that I need.

I've solved this task in a clumsy way and am asking for tips on how to rewrite this solution.
Here is my query:

```
        $subquery = 'Select \'' . 
        implode('\' as id union Select \'', $var_array) . '\'';

        $query = "Select tmp.variable, 
        fields.content is NULL as content FROM  ({$subquery}) tmp
        LEFT JOIN fields
        ON tmp.id= fields.id";
```

Comment: How big is your array?

Comment: about 10 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1 - Use a temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (`id` INT, `variable` VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Insert the data into the primary table and do a normal `JOIN`.

Note that temporary tables are created in memory and are dropped when the connection is closed (when the php script is done).

### Option 2 - Query and add to result

Assuming that `$vars` are key/value pairs of id/variable

```
$ids = join(',', array_keys($vars));
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `fields` WHERE `id` IN ($ids)");

$data = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $variable = $vars[$row['id']];
    $data[] = $row + ['variable' => $variable];
}
```